# Ubuntu will not boot help

Tags: system-installation

[Failed] Failed to start Clean up any mess left by Odns-up. See systemctl status dns-clean.service for details.

My screen is stuck saying this on boot...

Comment: Did you install any new software recently?

Comment: I was updating but it got cut short. Now I have no clue on what to do.

Comment: Press [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F1]. Then log in with your username and password. You password will not show up as you type (not even ***) but the computer is still accepting the characters.

Comment: Does anything happen when you press ctrl + alt + f1?

Comment: Yes i get my computer name with login: but I typed the password and then it asks for a password I feel retarded..

Comment: Okay I logged in but it's text telling me the error and that my update did not finish.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update || sudo apt-get install -f || sudo apt-get upgrade || sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update || sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will fix your issue. The command will check repositories for new packages and then install any missing dependencies for already installed packages.

Comment: I got this problem too and problem is, it doesn't boot into Ubuntu, it's just stuck on booting, no matter how many times I reboot.